# Magento2 : How to add state options for UAE

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, magento-2.1.7, billing-address, checkout-page

I want to add some specific states options in `State` drop down on checkout page for `UAE` country option.

I didn't find any setting for this.

I have to create a custom module or need to change in any file? What should I do?

Comment: In Magento2 any setting not available for add new states for the particular country. If you are need then run sql query in database.

Comment: @Abdul, Can you please post an example for that query?

Comment: Try this: INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` VALUES
    (NULL , 'AE', 'AUH','Abu Dhabir'),
    (NULL , 'AE', 'AJM','Ajman'),
    (NULL , 'AE', 'SHJ','Sharjah'),
    (NULL , 'AE', 'DXB','Dubai'),
    (NULL , 'AE', 'FUJ','Fujairah'),
    (NULL , 'AE', 'RAK','Ras Al Khaimah'),
    (NULL , 'AE', 'UAQ','Umm Al Quwain');

Comment: Thanks it is working, But Is there any way to add specific to one website as I have multi websites, right now options are showing for all websites.

Comment: have you need UAE only one website?

Comment: I have multi-website, on one website allow country is only UAE and state options should be some specific, for all other website state field will be as text field for UAE.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way you can insert new states to your Magento 2 via the setup file just follow the below steps

- Create a new module at **`Magento_root/app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}`**
- create below files into it as per the locations

> Magento_root/app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/module.xml
>   Magento_root/app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/registration.php
>   Magento_root/app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Setup/InstallData.php
>   Magento_root/app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/book1.csv

Code for **InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Abhishek\Addstate\Setup;

use \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $fileCsv 
    ){
        $this->_moduleReader =$moduleReader;
        $this->_fileCsv =$fileCsv;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){

        $setup->startSetup();
        $data = $this->getCSV();

        $num = count($data);
        echo "<pre>";
            for ($c=1; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $data1 = $data[$c];  
                $code = $data1[0];
                $StateName = $data1[1];
                $setup->getConnection()->Insert(
                    $setup->getTable('directory_country_region'),
                    [
                        'country_id' => 'IN',
                        'code' => $code,
                        'default_name' => $StateName
                    ]
                );
            }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    public function getCSV(){
        $directory = $this->_moduleReader->getModuleDir('etc', 'Abhishek_AddState');
        $file = $directory . '/book1.csv';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
        $data = $this->_fileCsv->getData($file);
        return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

**book1.csv**

```
code,Statename
AN,Andaman Nicobar
AP,Andhra Pradesh
AR,Arunachal Pradesh
AS,Assam
BH,Bihar
CH,Chandigarh
CG,Chhattisgarh
DN,Dadra Nagar Haveli
DD,Daman Diu
DL,Delhi
GA,Goa
GJ,Gujarat
HR,Haryana
HP,Himachal Pradesh
JK,Jammu Kashmir
JH,Jharkhand
KA,Karnataka
KL,Kerala
LD,Lakshadweep
MP,Madhya Pradesh
MH,Maharashtra
MN,Manipur
ML,Meghalaya
MZ,Mizoram
NL,Nagaland
OR,Odisha
PY,Pondicherry
PB,Punjab
RJ,Rajasthan
SK,Sikkim
TN,Tamil Nadu
TG,Telangana
TR,Tripura
UP,Uttar Pradesh
UT,Uttaranchal
WB,West Bengal
```

- Now run the below command from your Magento_root in terminal

  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Here in my answer I have used Indian States for example you can use whatever you want but make sure to use the **`country_id`** as per available into the database

> **Note:** do not run the sql queries directly or do not do entries directly to > the data base it is not considered as a good practice of Magento as preferred > that to insert any data into the database use setup script always

Comment: I agree with you, but please check my last comment above, I have multi-website and only want to add state options for one website only.