# Table Rates Shipping - UAE States Code issue

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento2.4, table-rates, country-regions

I am adding Custom shipping rates according to state of UAE in Table rates shipping method. But getting an error because  region or state is incorrect.

anyone have idea which is correct region/state code for UAE states (Dubai, Abu Dhabi, Sharjah, Ajman, Fujairah, Ras Al-Khaimah & Umm Al Quwain)

Please check attached screenshots of Table Rate file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check validation rules in the `vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/ResourceModel/Carrier/Tablerate/CSV/RowParser.php`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve region id from provided row data.
 *
 * @param array $rowData
 * @param int $rowNumber
 * @param ColumnResolver $columnResolver
 * @param int $countryId
 * @return array
 * @throws ColumnNotFoundException
 * @throws RowException
 */
private function getRegionIds(array $rowData, $rowNumber, ColumnResolver $columnResolver, $countryId)
{
    $regionCode = $columnResolver->getColumnValue(ColumnResolver::COLUMN_REGION, $rowData);
    if ($countryId !== '0' && $this->locationDirectory->hasRegionId($countryId, $regionCode)) {
        $regionIds = $this->locationDirectory->getRegionIds($countryId, $regionCode);
    } elseif ($regionCode === '*' || $regionCode === '') {
        $regionIds = [0];
    } else {
        throw new RowException(
            __(
                'The "%1" region or state in row number "%2" is incorrect. '
                . 'Verify the region or state and try again.',
                $regionCode,
                $rowNumber
            )
        );
    }
    return $regionIds;
}
```

By default the 2.4.4 Magento did not have predefined regions for the UAE, so you can't specify a region in the CSV (except empty string or `*` which means ***Any Region***).

If you want to use regions you must add them manually in the table `directory_country_region` (it is pretty easy) or you could use [this module **(paid!)**](https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-shipping-suite.html) to add them through admin side.

Seems like this is a correct sql for adding the UAE regions (taken from [Magento2 : How to add state options for UAE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221298/37497) ):

```
INSERT INTO directory_country_region VALUES (NULL , 'AE', 'AUH','Abu Dhabir'), (NULL , 'AE', 'AJM','Ajman'), (NULL , 'AE', 'SHJ','Sharjah'), (NULL , 'AE', 'DXB','Dubai'), (NULL , 'AE', 'FUJ','Fujairah'), (NULL , 'AE', 'RAK','Ras Al Khaimah'), (NULL , 'AE', 'UAQ','Umm Al Quwain');
```

Comment: Thank You, It's working fine.

Comment: @WajahatBashir I’m glad to help you :) Happy coding!